# How to parse multiple records in Json

Tags: c#, .net, json, parsing

Hello I am trying to parse a Json response into a class. So here is how the response looks...

```
[{"id":103,"customer_id":0},{"id":110,"customer_id":1}]
```

I was able to parse one line okay (I removed the '[' ']' and put it into one class). The problem is when I have multiple records, like this, that I am having an issue. This is how I am parsing the data...

```
        [DataContract]
public class Order
{
    public List<OrderRow> Orders { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class OrderRow
{
    [DataMember(Name = "id")]
    public int id { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "customer_id")]
    public int customer_id { get; set; }
}

StreamReader jfile = new StreamReader(@"path\test.json");
string json = jfile.ReadToEnd();
jfile.Close();

byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);
MemoryStream mStream = new MemoryStream(bytes);

DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Order));
Order jsonOrder = (Order)serializer.ReadObject(mStream);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of creating `Order` class, try to deserialize it directly into `OrderRow[]` array:

```
DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(OrderRow[]));
OrderRow[] jsonOrderRows = (OrderRow[])serializer.ReadObject(mStream);
```